# Solid of revolution problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I would like to check with you guys if this exercise is right. The problem is:

"Let be $R$ be the region bounded by the graph of $y=2x$", $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$ and $y=2$. Find the volume of the solid generated by the rotation of the region $R$ about the $y$-axis. Make a sketch of the region. Show your calculations."

This is the graph I made:

[image]

This is what I did:

Since we are integrating with respect to $y$ I solve for $x$ both equations. $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$ becomes $x=2\sqrt{y}$ and $y=2x$ becomes $x=\frac{1}{2}y$. So for the volume:

$$V=\pi\int_{0}^{2} ((2\sqrt{y})^2-(\frac{1}{2}y)^2) \,dy$$

$$V=\pi\int_{0}^{2} (4y-\frac{1}{4}y^2) \,dy$$

$$V=\pi(4\cdot\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{y^3}{3})\bigg|_{0}^2$$

$$V=\pi(2y^2-\frac{1}{12}y^3)\bigg|_{0}^2$$

$$V=\pi[(2(2)^2-\frac{1}{12}(2)^3)-(2(0)^2-\frac{1}{12}(0)^3)]$$

$$V=\pi[(2(4)-\frac{1}{12}(8)]$$

$$V=\pi[(8-\frac{2}{3}]$$

$$V=\pi[(\frac{24}{3}-\frac{2}{3}]$$

$$V=\pi[\frac{22}{3}]$$

$$V=\frac{22}{3}\pi$$

Therefore the volumen of the solid of revolution is $\frac{22}{3}\pi$ cubic units.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Nice sketch : It looks good to me from a quick skim through: You can check your calculations online using, for example https://www.symbolab.com/solver/volume-calculator
There is also a nice Wolfram Alpha 'widget' for drawing the shapes that, with a bit of fiddling about, produces good images : https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=228bc7c11f6524e0a38ceab65fed8f0c
(Both are free)

Comment: What you have done is absolutely correct!

Comment: @MartinHansen  thanks for checking. I tried Symbolab but didn't give a result. So that's why I wanted to check here.

Comment: @MathLover thanks! <3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly correct.

You can also verify your solution by using the method of cylindrical shells.  For instance, the volume of the parabolic region *including* the cone is just $$\int_{x=0}^{2 \sqrt{2}} 2\pi x \left(2 - \frac{x^2}{4}\right) \, dx = \left[2x^2 - \frac{x^4}{8}\right]_{x=0}^{2\sqrt{2}} \pi = 8\pi.$$  Then subtract out the volume of the cone, which has a circular base of radius $1$ and height $2$, thus volume $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h = \frac{2}{3}\pi$.  This gives the desired volume $$\left(8 - \frac{2}{3}\right) \pi = \frac{22}{3}\pi.$$  We could also have computed the parabolic region's volume via disks, which is
$$\int_{y=0}^2 4\pi y \, dy = 8\pi.$$